# How to execute else if(xpathcondition) , If first xpathcondition fails?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/h3[contains(text(),'MOVENPICK HOTEL DEIRA')]")).isDisplayed())
{
}
else if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/h3[contains(text(),'HOTEL INN')]")).isDisplayed())
{
}
```

In the above code, if condition fails means how to execute else if(xpathcondition), 
For failed condition its showing exception as "Element not Found". If I handled exception, how to execute else if??
Advance thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally `isDisplayed()` should return false instead of throwing exception.

You can go with saifur answer. Another approach would be  (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946703/selenium-webdriver-using-isdisplayed-in-if-statement-is-not-working))

```
try {

 if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/h3[contains(text(),'MOVENPICK HOTEL DEIRA')]")).isDisplayed())
    {  }

}catch(){  //catch executes the else part when the exception is thrown.

    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/h3[contains(text(),'HOTEL INN')]")).isDisplayed())
    {    }

}
```

---

Check this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1115) as well

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is if any of the elements look up fails the test will be terminated with *NoSuchElement* or *Element not Found*  exception since element is not a part of the dom. To avoid this you can trick the code a little bit or do another check to see if the element exists first.

I would rather find the element and match the text instead and perform additional task

```
// Write a selector that would meet the find both elements
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div h3"));

if (element.getText().contains("MOVENPICK HOTEL DEIRA")) {
    //do this
} else if (element.getText().contains("HOTEL INN")) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do nothing and log some error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. But in that problem occurs for me as,
If(condition) fails, its not executing (else if) directly its executing third else part, any idea for this.

Comment: Hey I think need to store WebElement in a dynamic array with the help of driver.findElements. In that case else part has got executed.
Thanks for your Idea!!

Comment: Please provide me the html you are dealing with and I would see why it's happening. Specially I want to know if either one of those element become invisible or does away completely.

Comment: Hii you can check the below the site in that click Hotels part & provide City as "Dubai", after redirecting to search results choose any three hotels. can you give sample for that,
Url : https://holidaysonclick.com/

Comment: can you please give detail description about the issue.