# isDisplayed() was not working, am using pagefactory

Tags: selenium

```
if (wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(user.profileEdit)).isDisplayed()) {  
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(user.profileEdit)).click();
    System.out.println("RECORD FOUND");
    } else {
      System.out.println("NO RECORD FOUND");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't understand your problem. What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver - using isDisplayed() in If statement is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946703/selenium-webdriver-using-isdisplayed-in-if-statement-is-not-working)

Comment: Sory But the question is duplicated, kindly search for answer before asking

Comment: yeah i didn't search it properly.... now its working... thanks for helping...

Answer (score 0):

1. `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(user.profileEdit))` - if element will not be clickable, TimeoutException will be thrown and `.isDisplayed()` will not be perform - you should choose `wait` or `isDisplayed` and rewrite your code accroding to it.
2. Element could be in frame if `wait` not work - you need just switch frame.
3. `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown in your case if `user.profileEdit` 
   element were initialized before it have been appeared - you can rewrite your test like this 

   `test() {
       element.click();
       ....
       assertThat(driver.findElement(By.xpath("user.profileEdit")).isDisplayed())
            .as("RECORD NOT FOUND");
   }`

Comment: refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946703/selenium-webdriver-using-isdisplayed-in-if-statement-is-not-working